# How to convert Select (Transact-SQL) syntax to VB .NET

Tags: sql, vb.net

I am using VB .NET and I have a huge variable (Table A) in DataTable format. Table A has many columns. 
I need to create a subset of table (class DataTable) from Table A by checking the field value in each Column from Table A.

There is a function in SQL, which matches the requirement above. It is called as SELECT (Transact-SQL). I have found the SQL description in the websites below:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189499.aspx and 
http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_where.asp.

My question:
What is the equivalent command in VB .NET which performs same task on DataTable?

I have checked various sources on converting the SQL command above to VB .NET. The Select Case in VB .NET works as an if condition checking.

Thank you.

Comment: Did you check the [DataTable.Select method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/det4aw50%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)?

Comment: There are about as many ways to do this as there are programmers. Can you narrow down your requirements?

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn, consider Table A has column A, B, C, D, and E. How do I create a subset of table (Table B), which has column B, C, D? Is there a built-in command? Or I need to loop manually?

Comment: @user2150279 There at least 1/2 dozen ways to do this: dataview, datatable.select, linq, new query, loop through rows, etc. What is best depends on what else you're doing.

Answer (score 0):

Your best approach, if you need the result to also be in a `DataTable`, is likely to be creating a [DataView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataview(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
Dim sourceTable = new DataTable()

....

Dim myView = new DataView(sourceTable, "selected = 1", "", 
                                                  DataViewRowState.Current)
Dim newTable = myView.ToTable()
```

The second parameter is the `where` clause part of a SQL `SELECT` statement, whilst the third allows you to add sorting to the result. The final parameter allows you to select a subset of the original rows if required.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the [DataTable.Select](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/det4aw50%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method.